# Change page content without reloading it, but keep an element untouched

Tags: jquery

I was asking if i could change the main content of an page without fully reloading it. I would like that an element doesn't get touched, some like save the data from this div element on the cache. I didn't find anything yet...

Comment: You can use ajax for that

Answer (score 0):

If your element is in the container, you wish to update, i would say its very difficult to impossible to do that.
Else have a look on [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)